# Combobox Array PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-selected-items

How do I store multiple items selected from a combobox into a global variable (array) to pass it to the next screen?

[image: Combobox Function]

Answer (score 1):

here is how I did it. I'm attempting to switch combobox to checkboxes so I hid the combox and put its contents into a collection like this

```
Clear(colVehiclesRequested); 
ForAll(DataCardValue4.SelectedItems, Collect(colVehiclesRequested,ThisRecord.Value));
```

where colVehiclesRequested is the collection and DataCardValue4 is the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

I heard of the following :

Last(FirstN( First( First(allData).input ).myData , 5))

(https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Is-it-possible-to-select-specific-item-from-an-array-or/td-p/14592)

But I don't know how to use it.